# How can I implement snapping tabs in PyQt?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to implement tabs that create a new QTabWidget when they're dragged to certain parts of the window. Is this possible to implement using a QTabWidget?

Comment: You probably want `QDockWidget`'s.  They can be dropped on top of other dock widgets that form tab widgets.

Comment: I've been trying to implement this, but I want the dock widget to basically function as the central widget and I'm not 100% sure on how to acomplish this.